# Why "c" is equal to 1000 here?

Tags: r, loops, distribution, break

This loop is going over all the values of `i` in `range(92:1000)` and whichever value of `i` is holding the condition true it is breaking the loop by setting that value of `i` in `c` and when i am trying to run this code block in R language it is giving me c=1000.

```
> c=0
> for (i in range(92:1000)){
+     if(dpois(i,94.32)<=dpois(5,94.32))
+         {c=i;
+         break;
+         }
+ }
> c
[1] 1000
```

But what i expected it should give value of c=235 as at i=235 as:--

```
> dpois(235,94.32)
[1] 2.201473e-34
> dpois(5,94.32)
[1] 6.779258e-34
> dpois(235,94.32)<=dpois(5,94.32)
[1] TRUE
```

And it should break whenever the condition is true for the first time.

Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: Range does not do what you think it does, that's a python command. Use just  92:1000.

Comment: To determine why what @user2974951 said is the right answer, run through this step by step. Steps, out of order: (2) Assign the first value from `range(...)` into `i`; (3) `dpois(i,94.32)` and `dpois(5,94.32)`; (4) assign the next value from `range(...)` into `i`; (5) `dpois(i,94.32)` and `dpois(5,94.32)` again; but the first step should be very englightening: (1) since you expect it to be a long vector, no need to flood the console, just use `head(range(92:1000))` (or `length(range(92:1000))`) ... though you expect `92 93 94 ... 998 999 1000`, you'll only see `92 1000`, two values.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks @user2974951 , it worked

Comment: @Abhisheksoni As an aside: better don't call your object `c` since that is a built-in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R, `range` computes the range of the given data, i.e. the minimum and maximum

```
> range(92:1000)
[1]   92 1000
```

Also, using `c` as a variable name is very bad practice in R. Since `c` is an intrinsic function used to define vectors.

The following gives the expected answer

```
> c0=0
>  for (i in 92:1000){
+        if(dpois(i,94.32)<=dpois(5,94.32))
+              {
+          
+              c0=i
+              break
+              
+              }
+    }
> c0
[1] 234
```

Comment: Of course, it would be better to do without the loop altogether, since `dpois` is vectorised. You could replace the whole thing with `c0 <- 91 + which(dpois(92:1000, 94.32) < dpois(5, 94.32))[1])`